# How to apply the Product Rule of Derivation to get a weird proof?

Tags: calculus

I am in the section of the textbook on derivations using product/ quotient rules. But I don't understand this problem it's asking.

> Use the Product Rule to show that (f^2)' = 2ff '.

I've tried just working it through. It doesn't seem to provide any useful insight, or come to f^2'.

f 'f ' + 2f*f ''

f '^2 + 2ff ''

and the other side is just 2f

Comment: Hint: $f^2=fg$ in the special case when $g=f$. If you can write the product rule correctly for $(fg)'$ then you should get something other than $f'f'+2ff''$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is just the chain rule: $$((f(x))^2)'=2f(x)f'(x)$$ or you can take the product rule:
$$(f(x)\cdot f(x))'=f'(x)f(x)+f(x)f'(x)$$